# Lodash split object

Tags: javascript

how can i use lodash to split the following object into two arrays

the object is

```
{"M":
  [
   "Alpha",
   "Beta",
   "Zeta"],
 "F":
    [
     "Alpha",
     "Omega"
  ]}
```

I want it to be

```
var first =  [
   "Alpha",
   "Beta",
   "Zeta"] // contents of M

var second =   [
     "Alpha",
     "Omega"
  ] // contents of F
```

is that possible in lodash? and if not then how is it possible in vanillaJS

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Lodash for this. Just:

```
var first = theObject.M;
var second = theObject.F;
```

`first` and `second` will refer to the arrays in the object. If you want to *copy* them, then:

```
var first = theObject.M.slice();
var second = theObject.F.slice();
```

Comment: When in doubt go with a simple solution, not a library.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference, this can be done very easily in es6:

`const { M: first, F: second } = theObject;`